# How is it possible that I have more Unacked than workers?

Tags: rabbitmq, bunny

I have a queue with 1 worker. The impl. looks like that:

```
def work
    connection = get_connection
    connection.start
    channel = connection.create_channel
    queue   = channel.queue("crawl", :durable => true)

    multi_log " [*] Worker waiting for messages in #{queue.name}. To exit press CTRL+C"

    begin
      queue.subscribe(:ack => true, :block => true) do |delivery_info, properties, message|
        multi_log " [x] Worker received #{message}"
        process_work message
        channel.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
        multi_log " [x] Worker job done for #{message}"
      end
    rescue => e
      log.error e.message
      log.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
      connection.close
    end
  end
```

The consumer is blocking as long the job is executed. In my understanding this consumer is processing 1 job at a time. But what confuses me is that in the RabbitMQ Management UI I see sometimes 2 or 3 Unacked for that Queue. But how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Publishing side of your solution is filling up the queue (indirectly throug exchange - can't say how since you didn't provide details). The number of subscribers (workers) has nothing to do with number of unack-ed messages. Seems that in your case it's simple: publishers are faster than subscribers.

Comment: The documentation says something else: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-ruby.html. Unacked messages are messages which has been delivered to a consumer/worker but the consumer didn't set back an ack yet.

Comment: I see that I wrote something wrong: what I meant is that the number of msgs that are unack-ed grows because the of the publisher(s) but is of course reduced by subscribers. Just run the scenario with zero workers but control the number of messages published and see what happens

Comment: nope, I'm wrong. You were refering to acks from server to consumer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out yesterday night :) The problem was that prefetch was not set explicitly. If you set `channel.prefetch(1)` then the consumer will take only 1 message at once. if the prefetch value is not set the consumer takes as much messages as it can. So the complete code now look like that.

```
  def work
    connection = get_connection
    connection.start
    channel = connection.create_channel
    channel.prefetch(1)
    queue   = channel.queue("crawl", :durable => true)

    multi_log " [*] Worker waiting for messages in #{queue.name}. To exit press CTRL+C"

    begin
      queue.subscribe(:ack => true, :block => true) do |delivery_info, properties, message|
        multi_log " [x] Worker received #{message}"
        process_work message
        channel.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
        multi_log " [x] Worker job done for #{message}"
      end
    rescue => e
      log.error e.message
      log.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
      connection.close
    end
  end
```

Now the RabbitMQ Management UI shows for example that there are 9 messages ready, 1 unacked and 10 total. That's like expected.

By the way, in Java you set the prefetch like this `channel.basicQos(1);`.